# Linear regression with weighted points python

Tags: python, scatter-plot

ax.scatter(x = NewUFOTimes['one'], y = NewUFOTimes['three'], s = (NewUFOTimes['two']/10))

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNb9r.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4x0B.png)

How do I make a linear regression with the larger dots having more weight?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is `ax`? Python doesn't do scatter plots (or any other types of plots) out of the box—it is a general-purpose programming language, not a data science or mathematical programming language. Are you using matplotlib? Bokeh? Something else?

Comment: I have posted an answer for you which I think will solve your problem. Like many people, I like to answer questions that I think will help lots of people in future, and I think that's likely to be the case here. If the answer works for you, all I ask is that you spend a little time reading the [guide to writing a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, after that, edit your question to be much more descriptive and follow those guidelines. This will help future searchers with the same question find useful answers (and is good practice for next time!). Thanks.

Comment: [Linear Regression's fit method in scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) allows you to specific sample weights ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of work in Python the `numpy` module is a must-have.

I infer that you are working with `pandas` - if so, you'll already have this library installed as a dependency and I therefore think we can assume that the following will work:

```py
x = NewUFOTimes["one"].values
y = NewUFOTimes["three"].values
w = NewUFOTimes["two"].values
```

This should store the underlying `numpy` arrays in `x`, `y`, and `w`. I'm going to also assume `ax` is a `matplotlib` Axes object.

Next we will use `numpy`'s ability to fit a polynomial, in this case a first degree polynomial (linear fit). Out of the box, this fit supports optional weighting. [You can read the full documentation here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit).

Here's what that looks like:

```py
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

... #  code that produces your original plot

x = NewUFOTimes["one"].values
y = NewUFOTimes["three"].values
w = NewUFOTimes["two"].values

line = Polynomial.fit(x, y, 1, w=w)

fit_x, fit_y = line.linspace()

ax.plot(fit_x, fit_y, '-', label="Weighted fit")
```

Now, I don't know where your weights came from, so I don't know whether they will obey the `numpy` documentation's suggestion that

> Ideally the weights are chosen so that the errors of the products w[i]*y[i] all have the same variance.

Perhaps you are using inverse-variance weighting. The documentation states:

> When using inverse-variance weighting, use w[i] = 1/sigma(y[i]).

It's important to be thoughtful about how you introduce weightings into the fit. Linear regression typically assumes homoscedasticity (i.e. 'all weights equal') so you should be sure your introduction of weights is well-motivated and well-executed.

---

As a quick aside, the 'old' way to do this was to use `numpy.polyfit`. However, the docstring for that function now includes the proviso

> The `Polynomial.fit <numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit>` class
> method is recommended for new code as it is more stable numerically. See
> the documentation of the method for more information.

It is worth noting that there is a trade-off. You may still wish to use the old method if it is important to you to receive the covariance matrix associated with the fit (`cov=True` option with `polyfit`). However, if that's not important then the above approach is likely best. I should add: [the use of weightings in the fit likely prevents the covariance matrix from being useful anyway](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22800/what-are-the-dangers-of-violating-the-homoscedasticity-assumption-for-linear-reg)!